# Is it OK to overwrite a file created by mktemp?

Tags: mktemp

I'd like to copy a file to a temporary location.

I'd like to make sure I'm not overwriting anything important, and that I know the location of the file while the script is running.

```
#!/bin/bash

myfile="$(mktemp)"
cp "source" "$myfile"

# work with $myfile

rm "$myfile"
```

Does this seem OK? Is there anything I'm missing? (Permissions, etc.?)
I have a bad feeling about overwriting that file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the man page

> Create  a  temporary  file  or  directory,  safely, and print its name.

You could add a check for whether `mktemp` was successful.

```
myfile="$(mktemp)"
if test $? != 0; then
  exit 1
fi
```

If `mktemp` succeeds, it has created a file that was not present before. You can safely overwrite that file, that is the purpose for using `mktemp`. The permissions are set to `u+rw`, as mentioned in the manual.